# How do I maintain linebreaks and indenting when submitting HTML to a server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have a HTML `<textarea>` that I am using to paste HTML into. 
The contents of the textarea are then being submitted to a firestore server.

I then render the HTML into:
`<p white-space: pre-line;>HERE<p>`

This approach will maintain the line breaks **but not** the indenting.
This:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Test code</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Becomes this:

```
<div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Test code</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

How would I go about maintaining the indenting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ReactHtmlParser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser). You can call it like this `ReactHtmlParser(yourHtmlString)`

Comment: Are you calling this at the `<textarea>` or where I am rendering to?

Comment: @Neil so you want `textarea` have the indentation when it loads? or are you displaying your html somewhere else different from textarea?

Comment: Ah I see. This will visibly render "Test code" string. The surrounding HTML will still be operating but thats not the exact result I need. I want to also render the surrounding HTML. (so that you could copy and paste it)

The `textarea` submits the HTML to the server. I then display the HTML somewhere else but want to maintain the formatting and show the HTML.

Comment: @Neil have you tried `<textare value={ReactHtmlParser(yourHtmlString)}></textarea>` ? this will help to indent your html in your editor.

Comment: thanks for the help. I found an answer myself but ReactHtmlParser is definately a useful tool I haven't come across before. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Neil please accept my answer and please post your solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question. 
Just wrap the outputted code from the server like so.

```
<pre>
  <code>OUTPUT</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: Excellent... :)